# Recent linux mint update (8th August 2021) has killed my Linux VM guest

Tags: linux, windows-10, virtualbox, linux-mint, apt

I'm running a Linux Mint guest VirtualBox VM under a Windows 10 host OS. VirtualBox version 6.1.22 r144080 (Qt5.6.2)

I ran the updates for Linux mint 20.1 Ulyssa and I now get the following GUI:
[screen grab of VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSmn1.jpg)

All the text and graphics are corrupted. I can create a session (Ctrl-Alt-F1..) and the kernel appears to be fine. The updates have just killed the GUI it seems.

Any idea how to correct?

Answer (score 1):

Answers can be found [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=231&t=354698) [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=231&t=354451) and [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=231&t=354405)

Looks like the problem is known - Caused by 3D acceleration on some systems